# My primary partition is inactive but "healthy"

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

My one partition said it's a primary partition and healthy. But it's not an active partition and I can't create it as active. Look at the picture.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ls2Tb.jpg]

How can I enable it?

Comment: Only one partition can be marked active. Are you sure none of the other two are marked as such ?

Comment: To clarify: "Active" does not mean the partition is active. It means "Boot from this partition".

Comment: Ok. i want use that partition as D: . How to enable?

Comment: I'm having the same problem too. I wonder if it's because it's formatted as non-NTFS.... not sure